# NFT - what is actually stored on the block chain to represent the digital asset?

Tags: ethereum

According to Wikipedia's entry on [NFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-fungible_token) the minting process "creates a copy of the file recorded on the digital ledger as an NFT".  Is that literally true of Ethereum based NFT for example?  For some reason I was under the impression that what is actually stored inside the blockchain is the cryptographic hash of the underlying digital asset, and possibly a reference to the file's location, not the actual file itself.  I guess it's easy enough to store the whole file when it is a jpg, or a 30 second video clip, but if you wanted to represent say "The Godfather" as an NFT, that would really bloat the blockchain if the entire film in 4K (about 11Gb?) had to be saved in the block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is in fact hash of the image file, URL of an off-chain resource, or sometimes just a simple ID with no other data.

Take [this random](https://opensea.io/assets/0xd0e7bc3f1efc5f098534bce73589835b8273b9a0/339) NFT token for example. The contract address is [0xd0e7bc3f1efc5f098534bce73589835b8273b9a0](https://etherscan.io/address/0xd0e7bc3f1efc5f098534bce73589835b8273b9a0#code) and the token ID is `339`.

If you call the function `tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)`, it retrieves data from a mapping `mapping (uint256 => string) private _tokenURIs`.

The string value for the ID `339` is https://metadata.thetwentysix.io/cryptocats/339. And yes, it is a (off-chain) JSON file that contains link to the actual image https://cryptocats.thetwentysix.io/contents/images/cats/339.png

Comment: Thanks I thought so.  Somebody should update the wikipedia entry.

Comment: Wikpedia fixed!

Comment: Just for clarity, there is no requirement about what sort of data might be saved in the NFT to link the token to the digital asset?  ie. it could contain any of hash value, uri, or maybe even nothing?

Comment: No requirement - at least on the Ethereum network under the [ERC-721](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-721.md) standard which is considered to be the original NFT standard. It even explicitly states that "_The metadata extension is OPTIONAL_". The metadata interface implements the `tokenURI()` function that usually returns link to an external resource.

Comment: rightclick. save as. stolen.

YoU WoUlD NoT FuNgE a ToKeN